# Ionic3 ActionSheet: How to use Custom Icons from Fontawesome?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3, font-awesome

I have the problem of using custom Icons from Fontawesome in my [ActionSheet](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/action-sheet/)  Buttons in Ionic3.

As far as I know you could add for example this code: 
`<i class="fas fa-ad"></i>`
in the `title/text` property of your actionsheet button and the Icon appeared.

But since Ionic 3 the `title/text` property is restricted to string only and this doesnt work anymore.

I also tried those fontawesome icons as png and then use them as custom css background like in this [Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43551463/add-my-custom-icons-to-ionic-2-actionsheets-buttons) but this also doesnt work. The images just dont get shown.

So I just ended up using those ionicons, which are provided by ionic as icons, like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { Platform, ActionSheetController } from 'ionic-angular';


@Component({
  templateUrl: 'basic.html'
})
export class BasicPage {
  constructor(
    public platform: Platform,
    public actionsheetCtrl: ActionSheetController
  ) { }

  openMenu() {
    let actionSheet = this.actionsheetCtrl.create({
      title: 'Albums',
      cssClass: 'action-sheets-basic-page',
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Delete',
          role: 'destructive',
          icon: !this.platform.is('ios') ? 'trash' : null,
          handler: () => {
            console.log('Delete clicked');
          }
        },
        {
          text: 'Share',
          icon: !this.platform.is('ios') ? 'share' : null,
          handler: () => {
            console.log('Share clicked');
          }
        },
        {
          text: 'Play',
          icon: !this.platform.is('ios') ? 'arrow-dropright-circle' : null,
          handler: () => {
            console.log('Play clicked');
          }
        },
        {
          text: 'Favorite',
          icon: !this.platform.is('ios') ? 'heart-outline' : null,
          handler: () => {
            console.log('Favorite clicked');
          }
        },
        {
          text: 'Cancel',
          role: 'cancel', // will always sort to be on the bottom
          icon: !this.platform.is('ios') ? 'close' : null,
          handler: () => {
            console.log('Cancel clicked');
          }
        }
      ]
    });
    actionSheet.present();
  }
}
```

Do you guys know how to add fontawesome icons to ActionSheet Buttons? I cant seem to find any useful help.

Comment: Have you tried with only code of icon?

Comment: yeah still no icon gets displayed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest to do a similar thing to how you can change the icon within ion-tabs. [Ionic Forum (ionic tabs with custom svgs)](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/anyway-to-custom-the-tabbars-icon-with-my-own-svg-file/46131/36) The basic idea is to have Ionic do the heavy lifting of setting up the html and applying the css tags. Then you simply place your svg where their font icons (Ionic 3) would be, but you use names that don't exist in their icon set. This can be done within your app.scss

```
ion-action-sheet {
  ion-icon {
    width: 3rem;
    height: 3rem;
  }

  .ion-ios-trash-solid,
  .ion-md-trash-solid {
    content: url(../assets/icon/trash-solid.svg);
  }

  .ion-ios-share-alt-square-solid,
  .ion-md-share-alt-square-solid {
    content: url(../assets/icon/share-alt-square-solid.svg);
  }

  .ion-ios-play-solid,
  .ion-md-play-solid {
    content: url(../assets/icon/play-solid.svg);
  }

  .ion-ios-heart-regular,
  .ion-md-heart-regular {
    content: url(../assets/icon/heart-regular.svg);
  }

  .ion-ios-times-solid,
  .ion-md-times-solid {
    content: url(../assets/icon/times-solid.svg);
  }
}
```

Then the action sheet could be created using

```
let actionSheet = this.actionsheetCtrl.create({
    title: 'Albums',
    cssClass: 'action-sheets-basic-page',
    buttons: [
      {
        text: 'Delete',
        role: 'destructive',
        icon: 'trash-solid',
        handler: () => {
          console.log('Delete clicked');
        }
      },
      {
        text: 'Share',
        icon: 'share-alt-square-solid',
        handler: () => {
          console.log('Share clicked');
        }
      },
      {
        text: 'Play',
        icon: 'play-solid',
        handler: () => {
          console.log('Play clicked');
        }
      },
      {
        text: 'Favorite',
        icon: 'heart-regular',
        handler: () => {
          console.log('Favorite clicked');
        }
      },
      {
        text: 'Cancel',
        role: 'cancel',
        icon: 'times-solid',
        handler: () => {
          console.log('Cancel clicked');
        }
      }
    ]
  });
  actionSheet.present();
```

Also you would need to drop the needed svgs into src/assets/icon or another directory and modify the paths within the css if you were to choose a different location.

Comment: Ah thanks Ill try that and let you know if it worked!